# D365 Current user network alias on report

Tags: reporting-services, barcode, dynamics-365

I have a report and i need to show the network alias of the user who printed the report and the PrimaryPhone of the connected person . How can i do that in D365 because display methods doesn't work. There is any expression who gave me the networkAlias based on UserId?

Answer (score 0):

is an out of the box report created with a wizard or a custom Fetch Xml Report? if is the first case you don't have many options, if it's a fetch XML report you should be able to print the current user, and the phone number within the user. From D365 CE you don't have options to query AD in any way, you can write some custom code to move that data into CRM, and then read the data from the report. For anything more complicated it might be worth to look into power BI.